# Who keeps the Ether when a transaction triggers an exception?

Tags: transactions, security, history, exceptions

An [audit](https://github.com/LeastAuthority/ethereum-analyses/blob/master/GasEcon.md#exceptions) had

"Strong Recommendation: We recommend that exceptions cause all value to be returned to the sender, not the recipient."

What were the technical reasons for not implementing this recommendation?  What other parts or behaviors of Ethereum would have been affected if this was "fixed"?

Comment: how do you know it was not implemented?

Comment: @5chdn https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties#exceptional-conditions

Comment: That may be outdated, it hasn't been edited since March

Comment: Indeed the wiki hasn't been updated (yet) and the same audit notes that  the recommendation was fixed: https://github.com/LeastAuthority/ethereum-analyses/blob/master/Appendix.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of an exception, the state is rolled back, and all value remains with the sender. In the case of an exception, it is as if the transaction never happened, except that the gas is all given to the miner.

See [Exceptions in Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#exceptions-in-solidity) for more.